# CSS, Duplicate Title in paragraph text using CSS code

Tags: css

Iam new to CSS & trying to figure out a way to copy the Title in paragraph text using CSS code..

Lets say......

## My Red Apple

This is an ordinary paragraph. I want to duplicate my title (My Red Apple) at the end of this text with CSS coding

Answer (score 3):

This can not be accomplished with css, you would need a programming language like javascript or php.

Answer (score 1):

If the title is never going to change, you can apply the CSS psuedo-class `:after` to whatever element it is that you want the title to follow, then give it a 'content' style.

So if you wanted it to be after a `<p>` tag, you could give that `<p>` tag an id and apply the following style:

```
<p id="p1">My Title</p>

<style type="text/css">
    #p1 :after {
      content: "My Title";
    }
</style>
```

If you don't know what the title is going to be, you will have to program this behavior using javascript or a server-side programming language.

**UPDATE**

Here is a jsfiddle showing one way you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jerreck/8R7ZP/2/

You will need to add this script to your page either internally in your hmtl document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function WriteTitle() {
    var postTitle = document.getElementById('blogPostTitle');
    var appendedTitle = document.getElementById('afterPost');
    // innerText for IE, textContent for other browsers
    var postTitleText = postTitle.innerText || element.textContent;
    appendedTitle.innerHTML = postTitleText;
}
WriteTitle();
</script>
```

Or externally by saving it as a javascript file and linking it to your html document like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="where-this-file-is-on-your-server/myScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank for that prompt response, I never change title, I just keep updating blogs, during that I really dont want to repeat the Title-text individually in Paragraph. It would be really helpful if you could write that code in details with an example, as I am very new to CSS,

Comment: Just to be clear, whatever text you've placed within the quotation marks of the content style is what is going to be written after the element.  In other words, it's not going to change from blog post to blog post unless you write a script to do that for you.  If you'd like, I could give you an example script to show you how that could work, but I may not be able to get to it until after work today.

Comment: @user3204756 - I've updated my post with an example script you could try.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Great!!! please provide me those example whenever you get free time, further I noticed that many say it can be done easily with javascript, if yes can I include those javascripts code in to my CSS? if yes, is it possible to get an example?, Thanking you in advance

Comment: @user3204756 - Ha, looks like we posted about the same time :)

Comment: Thanks alot, will go through your examples,, :)

Comment: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
function WriteTitle() {
    var postTitle = document.getElementById('blogPostTitle');
    var appendedTitle = document.getElementById('afterPost');
    // innerText for IE, textContent for other browsers
    var postTitleText = postTitle.innerText || element.textContent;
    appendedTitle.innerHTML = postTitleText;
}
WriteTitle();
</script>
<h1>CSS example!</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph and the Title called <var appendedTitle> </p>

</body>
</html>'

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know even how to post the codes here, I'm very new although i thought i can make it out, but could not :(, if you get freetime please advice, sorry for bothering at you...Iam a dummie, thanking you in advance.

Comment: Ha, no worries, I think I can see the problem already.  Try moving your script to the end of your HTML document, after all the elements that you need it to target.  Also, I had one mistake in the script I linked, take a look at the new link in the edited answer above.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h1>CSS example!</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph and the Title called... <var appendedTitle> </p>


<script type="text/javascript">
function WriteTitle() {
    var postTitle = document.getElementById('blogPostTitle');
    var appendedTitle = document.getElementById('afterPost');
    // innerText for IE, textContent for other browsers
    var postTitleText = postTitle.innerText || element.textContent;
    appendedTitle.innerHTML = postTitleText;
}
WriteTitle();
</script>


</body>
</html>`

Comment: sorry I tried editing, but it was not success, it would be really helpful if you correct my above code...... THank you :)

Comment: Apply the appropriate IDs to your elements.  <h1> needs to be <h1 id="blogPostTitle"> and <p> needs to be <p id="afterPost">

Comment: Again sorry to say no... :(, spent few hours on it, could not make it, I feel something short on it... could you check it please ?????????

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="blogPostTitle">CSS Example</h1>

<p id="afterpost">This is a paragraph and the Title called...</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function WriteTitle() {
    var postTitle = document.getElementById('blogPostTitle');
    var appendedTitle = document.getElementById('afterPost');
    // innerText for IE, textContent for other browsers
    var postTitleText = postTitle.innerText || element.textContent;
    appendedTitle.innerHTML = postTitleText;
}
WriteTitle();
</script>

</body>
</html>"

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="header">CSS Exampleeee</h1>

<p id="Para2">I want the title </p> <p>to be added here</p>

<script>
var element=document.getElementById("Para2");
var element2=document.getElementById("header");
element.innerHTML=element2.innerHTML;
</script>



</body>
</html>